# What CNI is used (and what are the alternatives) in GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm confused with Google Cloud's documentation on GKE. In the [Compare network models](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gke-compare-network-models) doc, it says GKE has a fully integrated networking model which suggests to me it has its own CNI implementation. However, in the [Network policies](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy#overview) section it says something about Calico. Yet, when I tried to check the config directory on one of the worker nodes of my GKE cluster -  `/etc/cni/net.d`, I've noticed a config file named `10-containerd-net.conflist` which would suggest a *containerd* CNI plugin?

Also in the [GKE Dataplane V2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dataplane-v2) doc, it says it is implemented using Cilium. Do I understand correctly that for clusters with Dataplane V2, GKE uses Cilium CNI then or is it just referring to Cilium solution as a whole?

Is it possible to configure the CNI used in a GKE cluster in any scenario (with or without Autopilot etc.) and is my understanding of the doc somewhat correct? I'm really confused at this point (probably because of my weak overall understanding of these concepts).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is you've pretty much got it right.

- GKE v1 it's their own CNI but if you want to go beyond Kubernetes Network Policy you can use Calico's Network Policies. The underlying CNI is still Googles.
- For V2 Google forked Cilium, so the CNI is derivative of Cilium but not Cilium. Cilium features won't work.
- No you can't do anything to GKE to change the CNI.
- Autopilot is always configured to use their default CNI.

Comment: And for checking if you are V1 or V2, check if you have cilium pods `kubectl -n kube-system get pods -l k8s-app=cilium -o wide`, they are called "anetd"